# Show all products for specific categories

Tags: magento2, category, frontend, magento2.4

Our client has a specific need where they wish all products to be shown for ***one*** particular category, whilst all others show the default number (12 in our case) with pagination.

I know Magento doesn't offer this out of the box. I don't mind hard-coding it in e.g. an XML file instead of a full-blown extensible solution that allows the option to be toggled through the category manager.

Is there a way to achieve this through a layout file?

Answer (score 0):

create a xml file catalog_category_view_id_25.xml

where 25 is your category id.

in theme > Magento_Catalog > layout

Handle your requirement by modifying  list.phtml file under this.